# Заменить jquery на нативный js

Tags: jquery

```
 $('#longitude').val(lng)
```

мне нужно поменять этот jquery на нативный js подскажите как это сделать...

Comment: Почитать документацию JS.

Comment: `document.querySelector('#longitude').value = lng;`

Answer (score 2):

Вот так

```js
document.getElementById('longitude').value = lng
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(document.querySelector(".data").innerText);
console.log(document.querySelector(".data").getAttribute('_my_attr'));

document.querySelector(".data").innerText = "Новый текст";
```

```html
<div class = 'data' _my_attr = 'text'>Текст</div>
```

Comment: Так это получение, а в jQuery val с параметром записывает

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar, ну так не проблема - `document.querySelector(".data").innerText = "Новый текст";`